# how to do initialization in range-based for loop

Tags: c++, for-loop, foreach, compiler-errors

I'm trying to use indexes in range-based for loop, so I created code as follow. I refer to this website http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0614r0.html

```
#include <vector>

int main(void)
{
    std::vector<double> vector1(100);

    for (std::size_t _index = 0; auto& _value : vector1)
    {
        _value = 10 + 5;    //This code is for test.
        ++_index;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

However, it gives me several error messages (cannot deduce type of auto, cannot use uninitialized _value, etc. / Sorry, my language is not English and so are the error messages)

Why does this happen? When I use `if` statement with initialization like this,

```
if (bool is_valid = false; is_valid)
{
    //do something
}
```

it worked just as fine.

Comment: The document you linked is a proposal for a future change in the standard. I am not aware of any compiler currently allowing that syntax.

Comment: Initialization in [range-for](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) is supposedly coming in future C++20 standard..

Comment: Where did you get C++20- conformant compiler?

Comment: @SergeyA Back alley. From an old guy with a flying Delorean.

Comment: @user4581301 sharing would be caring :'(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This syntax is supposedly part of upcoming C++20 standard, see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for

There are currently no C++20-conformant compilers, so it is no wonder you are getting compilation errors.